# How can I make the client stay on until the server makes a connection?

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

Client:

```
public class MyClient {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws  IOException, SocketException,     ConnectException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Daytime client.");
    try{
    clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4321);
         while(true){
           in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
           String s = in.readLine();
           System.out.println("Here is the timestamp received from the server: "+s); 
           System.out.println("The program terminated with no error and no exception");
         in.close();     
         clientSocket.close(); 
         clientSocket.close();
        }
        }catch (ConnectException e){
         System.exit(0); 
        }catch (SocketException f){
         System.exit(0); 
        }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e); 
        System.exit(0); 
        }     
   }    
}
```

Server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyServer {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;

    System.out.println("Daytime server ready."); 

    try {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4321);
       while(true){
          clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 
          System.out.println("Request received.");
           out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
           Date timestamp = new Date ();
          out.println(timestamp.toString());
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        System.exit(0);
      }
      out.close();
      clientSocket.close();
      serverSocket.close();
      System.out.println("3"); 

    }
  }
```

Comment: to have some idea have a look at http://socket.io/ out of question context though

Comment: @vijay The question is about Java.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. The client can't *connect* until the server is listening. There are several problems with the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what your question means, but your code is nonsense:

```
public class MyClient {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws  IOException, SocketException,     ConnectException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Daytime client.");
    try{
    clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4321);
         while(true){
           in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
           String s = in.readLine();
```

At this point you need `if (s == null) break;`

```
           System.out.println("Here is the timestamp received from the server: "+s); 
           System.out.println("The program terminated with no error and no exception");
```

This isn't true. The program isn't terminating at all. It is in the middle of a `while (true)` loop. Either remove the loop or fix the message.

```
         in.close();     
         clientSocket.close(); 
         clientSocket.close();
```

You don't need to close the socket twice. You don't need to close it at all actually, as you have closed its input stream.

```
        }
        }catch (ConnectException e){
         System.exit(0);
```

Never ignore an exception. Print it.

```
        }catch (SocketException f){
```

Never ignore an exception. Print it.

```
         System.exit(0); 
        }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e); 
        System.exit(0); 
        }     
   }    
}

public class MyServer {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
```

There's no reason for these variables to be declared out here.

```
    System.out.println("Daytime server ready.");
```

This isn't true. It isn't ready until you've created the `ServerSocket`. Don't write misleading messages.

```
    try {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4321);
```

You can declare the `ServerSocket` here.

```
       while(true){
          clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

You can declare the `Socket` here.

```
          System.out.println("Request received.");
           out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
           Date timestamp = new Date ();
          out.println(timestamp.toString());
```

At this point you need `out.close()`.

```
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        System.exit(0);
      }
      out.close();
```

`out` can be null at this point.

```
      clientSocket.close();
```

This is redundant as you've closed its output stream.

```
      serverSocket.close();
      System.out.println("3");     
    }
  }
```

I suggest you fix all this and re-test.